# Why don't my local function declarations work if the function is static?

Tags: c, static

```
//#define static /*empty*/
int main()
{
    static int a();
    return a();
}
static int a() { return 0; }
```

This works fine if I delete (`#define static /*empty*/`) the **static** keywords, but with the **static**s it breaks with: `error: static declaration of ‘a’ follows non-static declaration` (gcc).

What's the reason for this behavior?

Comment: You need to declare functions before you call them. Turn on `-Wall` and you'll see warnings about "implicit declaration of function 'a'" etc. Either put the definitions of the functions at the top, or at least put in forward declarations there.

Comment: Don't use macros which hide changes of the control flow. This is hard to maintain and error-prone. Also `return` is not a function; don't use parentheses around the expression, this can shadow errors/typos.

Comment: @PSkocik: Ah, didn't see that - that's really not a good idea! Partly because people will not look for your declarations there, and partly because it won't work - `static` has a different meaning inside functions from outside...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not valid (and doesn't make sense) to declare a function inside another with `static` keyword. C standard explicitly prohibits this:

[C11 draft, 6.7.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.1p7):

> The declaration of an identifier for a function that has block scope
>   shall have no explicit storage-class specifier other than extern.

Comment: I think it would make perfect sense if it just acted as if the static declaration was in the global  scope (as functions don't nest). But thanks a lot for an  actual answer and not a best practices lesson.

Comment: Indeed. IMO, It'd be better if function prototypes/declarations are completely prohibited from within other functions (but such is the history of C). Re: "best practices" - I know what you mean. It's a bane on SO. I suppose every question needs to be qualified with "I promise I won't write code like this and will do my utmost to stop any writing like this. But I am only playing/experimenting some part of the language. If it's offended your practices or hurt your feeling in any way, my profound apologizes" just to be safe.